# Redirect function in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redirect, location

Inside an Angular project I have a function. When I run it, I expect to go to the home.

Inside my function I have a condition, if is true I want to redirect.

```
 if (condition) {
     location.url('/home');
     // code...
 }
```

Comment: I would suggest reading angular's [router](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) guide. Angular should handle all of the router changes. By doing `location.href = ...` you are using the native js redirect, which forces your app to refresh. (which hurts user experience)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

 if (condition) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly confused what you mean by "redirect". If you have a condition that determines the final location, then you can just use go to one or the other.

```
if(location) {
   $location.url('/home');
} else {
   $location.url('/otherDestination');
}
```

If you mean a true redirect that reflects in the window history, read about the `$location.replace` function provided by [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location). Scroll down to the section labeled 'Replace method'. Hope this helps!

```
$location.url('/otherDestination').replace();
```

Comment: i have a condition:       `if (task.id == id ) {
        location.url('/home');
        // code...
      }`

Comment: Can you please clarify? Are you asking how to redirect if task.id != id?

Comment: The condition isn't important. I was just confused on what you were asking. If you need to navigate to a different page if task.id != id then you could have an else statement where you have the location.url go to a different page (like in the answer if/else statement) right? I apologize if I'm misunderstanding the question but it seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Yyou can always use JS

```
window.location.href = 'xyz';
```